# Angular JS assistance with adding values and decimals

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Im working wiht some home automation tools which displays energy usage using some widgets created but others smarter than I.

I can get this to work, it will display usage in KW however its incorrect.

The same of the watts should be portion of a KW

### **Can anyone point me in the direction of resolving this so it shows 0.XX please**

```
<div class="widget">
  <div class="icon off">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 48 48">
      <use xlink:href="/static/matrix-theme/squidink.svg#thunder-1">
      </use>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="name">Power</div>
  <div class="valueGroup">
    <div class="value">
    {{itemValue('LivingRoomNum2')*1 + itemValue('KitchenNum2') | number:2}} kW
    </div>
    <div class="value">
      {{itemValue('LivingRoomNum1')}} W (Living)
    </div>
    <div class="value">
      {{itemValue('KitchenNum1')}} W (Kitchen)
    </div>
  </div>            
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that from function `itemValue()` returned value is of type **string** and this is causing wrong calculation. Make sure you parse the result as number. You can use `parseFloat()` when returning from `itemValue()`.

Check the sample:

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('AppController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);

app.run();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="AppController" class="widget">

  <div class="value">Wrong: {{'12.5' * 1 + '10' | number:2}} kW</div>
  <div class="value">Correct: {{12.5 * 1 + 10 | number:2}} kW</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `| number:2` filter within the `{{ }}` of the 2nd and 3rd values. This filter allows numbers to be shown in decimals. Also make sure the data isn't string.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="widget">
  <div class="icon off">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 48 48">
      <use xlink:href="/static/matrix-theme/squidink.svg#thunder-1">
      </use>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="name">Power</div>
  <div class="valueGroup">
    <div class="value">
      {{(itemValue('LivingRoomNum2')*1 + itemValue('KitchenNum2')*1)/1000}} kW
    </div>
    <div class="value">{{itemValue('LivingRoomNum1')}} W (P1)</div>
    <div class="value">{{itemValue('KitchenNum1')}} W (P2)</div>
  </div>            
</div>
```

This fixed it. My actual number is indeed a string